# BERT: AttributeError: 'RobertaForMaskedLM' object has no attribute 'bert'

Tags: python, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to freeze some layers of my masked language model using the following code:

```
for param in model.bert.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

However, when I execute the code above, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'RobertaForMaskedLM' object has no attribute 'bert'
```

In my code, I have the following imports for my masked language model, but I am unsure what is causing the error above:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForMaskedLM
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint)
```

So far, I have tried to replace `bert` with `model` in my code, but that did not work.

Any help would be good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of `RobertaForMaskedLM` code [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.html#RobertaForMaskedLM), you can observe that there is no object with the name `bert`. Instead, they have an object `roberta` which is an object of type `RobertaModel`

Hence, to freeze the Roberta Model and train only the LM head, you should modify your code as:

```
for param in model.roberta.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```